# Module Not Found Error while Pushing to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, github, heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

I understand that this issue has been raised numerous times, but I have tried almost all solutions available with no success. The thing is that I am capable of deploying to GitHub pages with no problem, but Heroku mentions I have some routing issue.

After the recent issue whereby Heroku removed Github integration with Heroku, I have been having trouble pushing code. Initially, my website worked fine, with automatic deployment via Github. However, when I try manually pushing via:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

I am facing this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './pages/MainPage' in '/tmp/build_8986ef5f/src'
```

I have tried removing this page, and the error will just change to another can't resolve path error.

My file directory is:

```
- build
- node_modules
- public
- src
    - pages
        - MainPage.js
        - SecondPage.js
        - ...
    - App.js
    - index.js
.gitignore
package-lock.json
package.json
```

Within the App.js file, I import the library through a relative path via:

```
import Home from './pages/MainPage';
```

Is there something wrong with my relative pathing? I have not changed the structure since deploying via Github so I don't know what's the error.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out the error. Apparently deploying to Github had resulted in some case-sensitive naming to go wrong. E.g. although I was deploying it as MainPage, it was deployed as mainpage for some reason.

This had resulted in being unable to find the file path.

I used:

```
heroku run bash
```

To figure out the error of naming convention. To fix it, I removed all affected folders with wrong casing deployment, committed changes, then readded them in and redeployed it. It worked after I did this.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @dfwgwefewfwe! I don't have enough reputation to comment on their post, but it definitely fixed it for me.

Just to add some extra information though for others that may be stuck with it:

My issue was that I had some assets that were in folders such as

```
Equipment
  /hands
    /gloves1.png
    /gloves2.png
  /feet
    /boots1.png
    /boots2.png
```

To make things more consistent, I just capitalized the first letters to be Hands and Feet

I ran that command

```
heroku run bash
```

and was able to find those folders that had been renamed, and they were still in their old version.

So back on my local copy, I moved the whole Equipment folder to another location, removed any references to the assets in the code, and pushed that up to heroku.

Now the Equipment folder was removed on the server, then I was able to revert my last git commit and push exactly what I was trying to push before and it worked.

I hope that this helps someone else!